# Replace ' with \' in C#

Tags: c#

In this variable, i would like to add some \ before every '.

```
string html = 
    "<a href=\"annee-prochaine.html\">Calendrier de l'annee prochaine</a>"

html = html.Replace("'", "\'"); //No change
html = html.Replace("\'", "\'"); //No change

html = html.Replace("\'", "\\'");
//html => <a href=\"annee-prochaine.html\">Calendrier de l\\'annee prochaine</a>
html = html.Replace("\'", @"\'");
//html => <a href=\"annee-prochaine.html\">Calendrier de l\\'annee prochaine</a>
```

I would like to get that after Replace :

```
//html => <a href=\"annee-prochaine.html\">Calendrier de l\'annee prochaine</a>
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Comment: You got many good (+1 all) answers, but... Please make sure you doing it for pure fun, not to write out HTML in ASP.Net WebForms/MVC as there are better ways to achieve proper HTML encoding. Note that "l'annee" likely may contain "`" instead of single quote...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I strongly suspect that you're looking at the strings in the debugger, which is why you're seeing doubled backslashes.

This version is absolutely fine:

```
html = html.Replace("\'", "\\'");
```

(The one using the verbatim string literal would be fine too.) Rather than looking at it in the debugger, log it or just serve it, and everything should be fine.

The fact that you're seeing it for the double-quote as well is further evidence of this. For example, this string:

```
string html = "<a href=\"anne...";
```

... does *not* contain a backslash, but your diagnostics are showing it, which is what I'd expect in a debugger.

Comment: Indeed, i was looking the string in the debugger.

Its working good.

Answer (score 7):

The backslash character is an escape character, so you either need to put 2 of them, or use the @ string modifier which ignores escaping.

```
html=html.Replace("'", "\\'"); // this should work
html=html.Replace("'", @"\'"); // or this
```

Comment: That works, i was looking the string in the debugger, that's why i saw \\' after replace.

Comment: I'm glad you got what you need; Skeet is the man.  That was a well written first question.

Answer (score 1):

```
 string html = "<a href=\"annee-prochaine.html\">Calendrier de l'annee prochaine</a>"

 html = html.Replace("'",@"\'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
html=html.Replace("'", @"\'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Either of these lines:

```
html=html.Replace("\'", "\\'");
html=html.Replace("\'", @"\'");
```

Should do what you want. Maybe the debugger is telling you there are double \ characters, but in reality there is only one.

EDIT: sorry, actually it should be `"'"` as the first argument.